# Usage of выходить and выйти в будущем времени

Tags: выбор-слова, значение

I know both words have a meaning of "leaving". But according to [this](http://learnrussian.rt.com/grammar-tables/verbs-of-motion-with-the-prefixes-v--vi/) **выйти** is supposed to be used in the case of predictable result, like:

> *Через 5 минут он выйдет из класса.*

While выходить is supposed to be used when two actions will be taking place at the same time:

> *Когда самолёт будет вылетать, информация на табло изменится*.

But in the exercises there's the following sentence:

> *Извините, вы выходите на следующей остановке? – Нет, не выхожу.*

It makes more sense to use выйти here since we're talking about a near future, so my question is why is **выходить** being used here?

Comment: @shabunc I'll have to contest this. This is not the same question. I'm not asking about "asking a question with perfective and answering it using imperfective". I'm asking about why an imperfective verb was used in this case. You should re-open the question IMHO

Comment: You can use "Вы выйдете на следующей остановке?" as well.

Comment: I think imperfect can be used in the same place where you can use "is going to" in English. "В следующем месяце я лечу отдыхать в Турцию." means "I am going to fly to Turkey next month."